# Is there any table for users' activity on data dump?

Tags: support, data-dump, recent-activity

I haven't found any table that has user history information in the Stack Exchange Data Dump. For example, when a specific user has asked, answered, commented, edited and his answer is accepted.

Where I can find this information?

Comment: Isn't that in the Votes and PostHistory tables?

Comment: Did you find this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede

Comment: Yes. I found. But I hope there is more easy way to retrieve the user activity as it is shown http://stackoverflow.com/users/412270/myborobudur?tab=activity    activity-->all tab

Comment: No, I'm afraid not. A query/subquery that joins those tables is needed

Answer (score 1):

We include this information in the data dumps already in the Posts, Comments, and PostHistory tables already. We don't include any other denormalized versions of this data since it would add to already enormous data dumps.

Speaking of - I need to go kick off a new data dump right now.

Comment: Will this data dump include suggested edits, close flags/votes, etc.?

Comment: @hichris123 the tables are the same as last time, and include whatever those tables currently hold in the Stack Exchange Data Explorer - that's what we match to. Flags and close votes we include in data explorer for querying what's currently in flight, but from a permanent archive perspective showing what's open *right now* makes almost no sense. For that reason, we don't include data that changes *very* rapidly in the archive.

Comment: How about suggested edits, though? They're more like posts: some are added but the rest stay the exact same.

Comment: @hichris123 Suggested edits are still edits, and are contained in the PostHistory table in the dump.

Comment: Yeah, however if I remember correctly the *votes* (approve/reject) aren't in there. i.e. the SuggestedEdits and the SuggestedEditVotes tables.